# How to change text size on Android Things?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things, text-size

I developed an application on `AT_v0.3` developer version, `Raspberry PI 3`. The application on `AT_v1.0` stable version size of text and other items are bigger and they are not visible.

Also, there is no option for sizes in the `settings` menu on `AT_v1.0`. So, is there a way to fix it without re-design the layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many changes that may have to be made to your applications between the third developer preview and the stable version. In addition to APIs, you may need to update your layouts.

In a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView), if the font size is too large or small, you can modify the XML contents to specify a specific font size:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

You can also use a [custom theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) in order to modify a number of `Textview` elements to adjust them all to the same extent.

Comment: Dear @Nick Felker. I tried your solution, and it works. Unfortunately, I have to re-design the layouts and other stuff. Because AT has been heavily changed since v0.3, not only layouts but the way of accessing IOs.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an assumption, however...

The key difference between *Android Things Dev Preview 3* (a.k.a 0.3) and the "stable" *Android Things 1.0* is that for the 1st you set up you display resolution manually via `config.txt` compared to the "stable" version where the system is configured via [Android Things Console](https://partner.android.com/things/console). You can treat the console as a black box which may downgrade a display density for the sake of more wide display coverage.

it would be sad if an *Android Things* developer had to "re-designing the layouts" in order to fit the configuration coming from the console.

Comment: It is not a good idea to directly modify the `config.txt` as there's no direct documentation and there are recommended ways to update layout contents.

Comment: @Nick Felker, many thanks for the comment! A couple questions though. How come an owner of hardware isn't recommended to modify its own hardware's `config.txt`? Why an hardware owner would update a high-level (software) "config" (xml-layout here) in order to fit the configuration coming from the console (pretty much a black-box)?

Comment: Dear @Onik. It seems I have to re-design the layouts and other stuff. Because AT has been heavily changed since v0.3, not only layouts but the way of accessing IOs.

Comment: @ierturk, sure! Do whatever works for you. It is, just as I said, wrong that an owner of hardware with specific specification should customise an app layout like if he'd develop an app for a wide range of different hardwares unknown in advance.